# Get NTP IP in windows servers

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, ntp

I kind of giveing up to find NTP IP address in 200 windows servers 2003 and 2008.
I tried powershell script ([Here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Determine-a-computers-time-4b3063e2)) and ([Here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/298638-ntp-script-to-retrieve-time-sources))

Still I couldn't get any NTP ip.
When I run `w32tm /query /status` in command prompt, I will get

> Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
>   Stratum: 5 (secondary reference - syncd by (S)NTP)
>   Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
>   Root Delay: 0.1293793s
>   Root Dispersion: 0.2016004s
>   ReferenceId: 0x00000000 (source IP:  **192.xxx.xxx.xxx**)
>   Last Successful Sync Time: 7/15/2014 3:39:07 PM
>   Source: Host.LocalDomain.com
>   Poll Interval: 12 (4096s)

I need some batch/shell that I could import severs list (windows 2003/2008/2008R2) and output would be **source IP**.
I just want to make sure all my servers are using same IP address.
That would be great if I could use other credential.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Batch file and powershell script are not programming?
I don't see any professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be returning the IP of NTP server. Prerequisites: RemoteRegistry running on the server and of course access to the remote registry.

```
$Serverlist = cat $env:userprofile\Desktop\Test.txt
    foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) {
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Server)
    $objKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentcontrolSet\\Services\\W32Time\\Parameters")
    $DNSNTP = $objKey.GetValue("NtpServer")
    $DNSNTP = ($DNSNTP = $DNSNTP.Split(','))[0]
    ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses($DNSNTP)) | Select -ExpandProperty IpAddressToString
    }
```

Edit:

Since it seems I misunderstood the question

Here is something that returns exactly the referenceID field from W32TM. This will however extract the data from the FIXED point. if something is different in your setup, you will have to manuever around calling the array elements, splits and substrings. On the other hand, the referenceID for me returns the IP address of ntp server if there is a domain one set... Plus, you have to have Enable-PSremoting -force set up on the servers for them to accept calls.

```
$Serverlist = cat $env:userprofile\Desktop\Test.txt
foreach ($Server in $Serverlist) { Invoke-Command -Command {(w32tm /query /status)[5].split(' ')[-1].TrimEnd(')')} -Computername $Server
```

Comment: Thanks,should RemoteRegistry runs in all servers or just in my host?

Comment: On all the servers. Its a listening service. I'm not sure but I often see it enabled, could be a default apparently

Comment: dummy question, is it ps1 script or batch?
Also, could I use different credential?
I will test it in next 2 hours.

Comment: Its Powershell script. Batch cannot utilise .NET classes. You will be able to use the script on every server where credential details are the same. If you need to elevate to 'admin' account (common practice) - use runas.exe /user:Adminaccount powershell.exe and then call the script. With at least basic IT intuition, you should manage :-)

Comment: How About this one: C:\PS> $cred = Get-Credential -Credential Domain\Account and then C:\PS> .\NTP.ps1 -Credential $cred

Comment: The script does not accept $Credential parameter, although I cant check at the moment. Never thought of calling the scripts this way with alternate creds, always used either RDP or through runas.exe

Comment: I ran the script, its gave me another IP address that I got with w32tm /query /status

Comment: Ugh, it seems I misunderstood your question, I'm redoing the answer now